# VBA For loop works once and then on second try it creates a Run-time error

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, runtime-error

I have created a system for ordering parts that runs a macro that searches for the parts ordered by the operator, by looking for a hidden cell that indicates that the item has been ordered. The macro works as intended the first time, but when the workbook is edited (say an item was added), and the macro is run again, it generates a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error (the bug line is commented),

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("PURCHASE ORDER")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("PICKING SHEET")

'Search for Ordered Units and add to Collection(Coll 9,"1" = Add row)
    For i = 19 To 150
        If Cells(i, 9).Value = 1 Then
            list.Add i
        End If
    Next i

'Clear Template
ws2.Range("A8:J45").Clear

'Add Purchase Date
ws1.Range("C5").Copy
ws2.Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Add Order data
ws1.Range("E3:E5").Copy
ws2.Range("E3:E5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Read Collection and add to "Order" sheet

For Each v In list
    'Debug.Print v
    'Formating Cell Borders
    ws2.Range("B8:J8").Offset(t).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    ws2.Range("B8:J8").Offset(t).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    ws2.Range("B8:J8").Offset(t).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    ws2.Range("B8:J8").Offset(t).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    ws2.Range("B8:J8").Offset(t).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    'Copy Function
    Debug.Print v
    'Bug Postion - Only happens after macro retry, row is defined
    Set data1 = ws1.Range(Cells(v, 3), Cells(v, 5))
    Set data2 = ws1.Range(Cells(v, 10), Cells(v, 10))
    data1.Copy
    ws2.Range("B8").Offset(t).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    data2.Copy
    ws2.Range("E8").Offset(t).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Formating Cell Alingment
    ws2.Range("B8:J8").Offset(t).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    'Paste Offset, every loop adds 1 and moves line to next row
    t = t + 1
Next v
```

Comment: What is the value of `v` when it works and when it fails? Also, the first time you execute this, I guess out collection `list` is empty, and the second one is not. Could that be?

Comment: As answers below suggest, you should always qualify your ranges with relevant worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before EVERY `Cells` you should specify `ws1` or `ws2`.
E.g.: `ws1.Cells`

---

Bonus.

```
ws1.Range("C5").Copy
ws2.Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

is equivalent to:

```
ws2.Range("C5") = ws1.Range("C5")
```

Plus this shorter version is performance-wise better.

Answer (score 1):

Common error. You need to qualify `Cells` when you assign the range, else the `Cells`-Object of the *Active Sheet* is used. If `ws1` is not the active sheet, this will cause the runtime error.

Write

```
Set data1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(v, 3), ws1.Cells(v, 5))
Set data2 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(v, 10), ws1.Cells(v, 10))
```

or

```
With ws1
    Set data1 = .Range(.Cells(v, 3), .Cells(v, 5))
    Set data2 = .Range(.Cells(v, 10), .Cells(v, 10))
End With
```